# Magento - Free product when purchasing a different product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I want a specific product to be free when added to the cart along with another product from a chosen category.

I've added the conditions below, but in actions I cant find an option to apply the 100% discount to a specific SKU, only products in a specific category or attribute set.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thank you

-

**Example**

> If a product in the cart is from category 3, then discount product with
>   SKU 'blah' by 100%

-

**Condition**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
        Category  is  3
```

-

**Action**

[image]

Comment: The only ive found I can do this is if I put the product that I will be giving away in its own category and choosing that category in the actions page. No ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to be sure that the SKU attribute can be used for the Promo rules creation. To do this, go to Catalogue/Attributes/Manage Attributes

[image: go to Catalogue/Attributes/Manage Attributes]

and edit the "SKU" attribute, setting the "**Use for Promo Rule Conditions**" attribute to **YES**

[image]

Then you can create such rules in the "Shopping Cart" price rules, with this conditions:
[image: 42 should be the your category 3]

Where "42" is you category with id: 3

And the following actions:

[image]
Where "Francis-orange" is you product with sku "blah".

In this way you will see the subtotal applying the 100% discount for the "blah" (Francis-orange) product.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see an option to apply the rules to just an SKU, please see screenshot in my OP.

Comment: Check in the attribute management, the SKU attribute should have the "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" value set as "YES"

Comment: There is no attribute management in the dropdown, just attribute set, and this just shows the attribute sets I have on products in my store.  EG T-Shirts etc.

Comment: Admin Top menu -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes
Then click on the "SKU" attribute and in the "Frontend properties" tab set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to YES 
Here the screenshot [link](http://it.tinypic.com/r/23s6dyv/8)

Comment: Legend. Thank you very much. Feel free to summarise the above and i'll mark it as the top answer.

Comment: @OliverEvans Glad it helped! I edited the answer to reflect all the steps to solve the problem! Cheers!